# Correct way to enable or disable PHP's 'display_errors' ini setting?

Tags: php, configuration, runtime-error, runtime, settings

I have come across different conventions to enable the display_errors .ini setting in PHP runtime:

```php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' );
ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', true );
```

And similar variations to disable it:

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'Off' );
ini_set( 'display_errors', '0' );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
ini_set( 'display_errors', false );
ini_set( 'display_errors', null );
```

They all seem to work, but it feels sloppy. Assuming PHP 7.1, what would be correct?

Answer (score 0):

enable it in your **php.ini** file

```
display_errors = On
```

disable it in your **php.ini** file

```
display_errors = Off
```

Then **restart** apache.

Comment: I meant to change it at runtime. But since you're explicitly using `On` and `Off` here for the php.ini file, would that imply I should also use the `'On'` and `'Off'` strings when changing it dynamically? (with the `ini_set` function)

Comment: Use this at run time

**ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);**